# UTC time zone calculation

Tags: sql-server, utc

We have data stored in our timezone ('AUS Eastern Standard Time') into SQL Server database, and we have to do calculations. Is it possible to convert both dates to UTC for calculations, so that it calculates the right difference?

```
DECLARE @startdate DateTime = '2022-10-01 23:13:00.000'; --UTC 2022-10-01 13:13:00.00
DECLARE @enddate DateTime = '2022-10-02 12:08:00.000' --UTC 2022-10-02 01:08:00.00
select CAST((@enddate - @startdate) as time(0)) 'Difference'

Time difference: 12:55:00

Actual Time Difference: 11:55:00
```

Comment: Do you store the offset anywhere? If not, you'll going to "have fun" with DST; especially if the time falls between the hour that the clocks go back.

Comment: As an example, take `2022-04-03 01:30`; how do you know if that's AEST (+10:00) AEDT (+11:00)?

Comment: @larnu So we have this in the data warehouse. We are sent values in the current time zone AEST or AEDT. I can make changes to how the dates are saved so it can work properly. Would some function while loading the data from the source can be used? So we can calculate the differences correctly. Is it possible to save the dates in UTC in memory, but display them as AEST or AEDT?

Answer (score 2):

Datetime values will be problematic without an offset as @Larnu suggest in comments. This will occur when clocks are set back and result in overlapping times before and after the time change. You'll need rules to determine the offset in that case.

In your example, where clocks are set forward, there should be no overlap or ambiguity. This allows one to use `AT DATE TIME AUS Eastern Standard Time')` to convert the datetime values to datetimeoffset for the duration calculation. If an invalid datetime value is stored (within the gap when clocks should have been change forward), `AT DATE TIME` will return the offset after the clock change.

```
DECLARE @startdate DateTime = '2022-10-01 23:13:00.000'; --UTC 2022-10-01 13:13:00.00
DECLARE @enddate DateTime   = '2022-10-02 12:08:00.000';  --UTC 2022-10-02 01:08:00.00
SELECT DATEADD(second
        , DATEDIFF(second, @startdate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'
        , @enddate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')
    , CAST('00:00:00' AS time(0)));
```

So you'll have one hour of the year you'll need to develop business rules for. `AT DATE TIME` [will return the offset before the change during the ambiguous interval when clocks are set backwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks).

Comment: This does work here but when I extract the dates from the tables this gives me a time difference of 12:05 instead of 11:55. Can you also suggest what changes can be done when loading the data from source to target? maybe a way that those dates are saved in UTC in the backend but the table shows them the current system time. and if we calculate, it uses the UTC time in the background.

Comment: @Doodle, add a simplified script to your question with `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that demonstrate the problem you see in your actual tables.

Comment: Thankyou Dan. I'll update what I did. The logic is almost there.

Answer (score 1):

DATETIME is a not recommended because it's a datatype with plenty of erronous features and it is not accurate.

Use DATETIME2 instaed (MS recommendation)

Then SET the TIMEZONE with the operator AT TIME ZONE :

Use ALSO DATETDIFF to get a difference because a minus sign must only apply to numbers not for date/time calculus...

Finally :

```
DECLARE @startdate DateTime2 = '2022-10-01 23:13:00.000'; 
DECLARE @enddate DateTime2 = '2022-10-02 12:08:00.000'; 
DECLARE @difsecond INT = DATEDIFF(s, @startdate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time', @enddate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')  
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(s, @difsecond, CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATETIME2(0))) AS TIME)
```